"Shop has been open all day/the whole day" " I have been awake all day/the whole day"
"Shop has been open all day/ the whole day (for the whole day).Does it mean shop is still open or shop has recently closed?
"I have been awake all day/the whole day(for the whole day)" does this mean I was awake but not anymore or does this mean i have not yet slept and state of being awake is still continue
I have been sick all week/the whole week(for the whole week). Does this mean continue sickness or sickness is over?

In all three examples, the states as described by the adjectives open, awake, and sick are still true.  Hence the shop is still open, you are still awake, and you are still sick.
Edit
If the sentences have used had been or was, they will mean the states were true prior to some subsequent past events.  Whether they are still true now is not known.  We need more elaboration to be sure of any changes in states, for example, until ...

Thanks but does same thing apply in past? As in "shops had been open" " I had been awake" "i had been sick" whether the shop was still open or not whether i was still awake or not whethet i was still sick or not

Hi, @Bilal Zafar, I've added more explanations to my answer.

.Cheers, actually i want to know regarding "had been adjective" as in he had been awake,sick,open.Whether at one point in time in past he was continuously staying awake or prior he had stayed awake?

There is no implication that the same thing is not true still. For example The door had been red for years when the painters came, and they painted it in the original colour.

Hi, @Bilal Zafar, I think you’re asking Whether he was continuously staying awake ... Yes he had been awake means he had stayed awake throughout.

The question Whether at one point in time in past he was continuously staying awake ... isn't good. This format would be good for asking Whether at one point in time in the past he somehow nodded off ...

Obviously you can't say I have been awake all day but now I'm asleep"! But I do find it idiomatic to say to a disappointed customer The shop has been open all day, but it's now 8 p.m. and the staff have gone home.

@SeowjoohengSingapore I am afraid I did not understand. If i say "He had been awake"  was he awake prior(as in yesterday,being awake happened yesterday or as in he had been awake for some time(continuity of being awake)?

@KateBunting in your example of disappointed customer "The shop has been all day......gone home" what does the shop has been open all day mean ?whether it means  shop has been open forso some time/continuity/still open or the shop has just been closed as in it was open a little time ago

I meant to say that, to me, The shop has been open all day  doesn't always have to mean that it is still open. I imagine that disappointed customer arriving at, or soon after, closing time and the speaker implying "You have had all day to do your shopping - why come so late?"

@Kate Bunting.Oh now i understand. Does past perfect could also have two meaning as in shop was not still open as in 1. "Shop had been open all day" why did not you come to do shopping. 2. Shop was still open.Shop had been open all day( shop had been open since 9 am) so i bought some biscuits

Yes, the past perfect could mean that the shop was still open or that it had recently closed depending on context.

Hi, @Bilal Zafar, I try to catch up here.  In your last question, you were asking whether He had been awake means the awakeness was continuous or only at some points.It depends on what you want to say.
He had been awake whole day, He had been awake most part of the day, and He had been awake for only two hours are all valid.Your original question mentions
awake all day/the whole day.  If that's what you want, then it means just that.

@KateBunting last query. As you said  in your previous comment "why come so late"?.Wont we say why+verb+noun/,adjective for imperative as in why i eat apple(more or less mean why should i eat apple? or is it a suggestion?.But why did use say it to disappointed customer when he is already late. Won't it be use for future reference?

Sorry - I was using informal speech which may not be familiar to you as an English learner. I meant that the speaker is implying "The shop has been open all day, so you could have come earlier; why have you come so late in the day?" (Of course, there may be a good reason why the person couldn't do their shopping earlier!) "Why I eat apple" is not a valid sentence and is not an imperative.
